# Is there a way to integrate yolov5 and svm?

Tags: integration, object-detection, svm, yolov5

I am currently working on an object detection project. I have already done it with yolov5 and svm separately can i integrate both the algorithm together like YOLO for object localization and detection and SVM for feature extraction and classification like a fusion strategy? If yes please tell me how, it can be of great use

Well i dont have any idea on how to integrate it